# `git log --graph`, but without `git log` (gitflow?)

Tags: git, version-control

Is it possible to get GIT to give a branching/tagging/merging history but without every log (commit) line?

I would graph where branches fork and merge, and summarize in-between commits to messages like 'X commits behind' and 'X commits diverged'.

This would be possible to with some scripting, but I have never seen a tool that does this. I would like to base this on a standardized gitflow[1].

Update: so what I've been looking for every now and then is a tool that actual offers an additional abstraction. Instead of dressing up standard GIT output and offering little over using CLI commands. Maybe I can answer my own question here, by stating that ungit[2] is the only one out there that tries.

[1] https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html
[2] https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit

Comment: Would it be possible? Probably. What's your question here?

Comment: There is nothing built-in (save `gitk` or so) that can do what you ask; you'll need to script or otherwise build something around the existing tooling.

Comment: I don't have ready answer but you could try options from [History simplification section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification)

Comment: So you mean what you want is a tool with the output you want instead of using git command line directly? But no matter for each tool, they realized the features by git command(s). And there are various of tool, different users may refer different tools.